# Get a Boolean value from an Object class in Java Using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am in search for the best approach to get a boolean value in Object class in Java8. The Object class structure is as follows.

```
class Object {
    boolean status;
    String name;
    // getters and setters
}

Object obj = getObjectValue();
```

`getObjectValue()` returns object. Whats the best approach, if I have to get status value in boolean.

Comment: What's `getObjectValue()`?

Comment: Having a custom class named `Object` is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: You probably imported the wrong `Object` class in your other class. Note that Java already has a class named `Object` and you then always need to specify which `Object` you want at which point. You probably used the wrong and thus `getObjectValue().status` or `getObjectValue().getStatus()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have those comment mentioned getters and setters, you can simply make use of them as:-

```
boolean output = getObjectValue().getStatus();
```

---

Additionally, make sure of this and I am not suggesting an approach/practice here -

If your Object class is as:-

```
package x.y.z; //notice 

class Object {
    boolean status;
    String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Your implementation of the custom method is as:-

```
x.y.z.Object getObjectValue() { ... } // notice the return type
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your getter:

```
boolean status = obj.getStatus();
```

and, as said in comment, rename your class name :)